# How do you cycle (close the existing and start a new) errorlog on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

How do you cycle (close the existing and start a new) errorlog on SQL Server?

Comment: Why post a question if you answer it in under a minute yourself...voted to close.

Comment: Because I thought the information would be useful to others. I understand this to be an acceptable (and perhaps encouraged practice). 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209329/stackoverflow-should-i-answer-my-own-question-or-not
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572/is-it-poor-etiquette-to-answer-your-own-question

Comment: Sounds like a way to rack up some reputation points to me but I will give you have the benefit of the doubt on this occasion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[sp_Cycle_ErrorLog][1]` for the SQL Server error log. This will stop the current one, and start a new one.

For SQL Agent Error Logs, you can use `[sp_Cycle_Agent_ErrorLog][2]`.

You can schedule this to run as required in your environment, just note that there is a limit to how many files and how many days of history that will be retained.

Answer (score 0):

There is a system stored procedure, `sp_cycle_errorlog`, that will do this.